# Gsoap undefined references

Tags: soap, reference, undefined, gsoap

I'm trying to use and web service with gsoap. I've already generated all *.h and *.cpp using wsdl2h and soapcpp2, included all libraries, at least I think so, but when I build the project it gives me the message of undefined references to a lot of methods. The thing is all methods are declared in soapH.h (the prototype) and in soapC.cpp (the implementation).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you included some generated header files in your build, which should not. (e.g. the .h file generated from wsdl) There are descriptions in the comment section in each generated files, and you'd better read them to get familiar how to use them. 
Also, if you use openssl, the library should also be included during linking process(-lssl)

Comment: Thank you, I've got the original header from the developer of the web service

Comment: Also, don't forget to include the nsmap file: `#include "YourWebServiceFileName.nsmap"` in the `.cpp` file the calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, All I need was the original header file, I was getting one from the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounteres this problem: you do not have to include all the .cpp files in your makefile - some of them are included by the other. What you need also depends on whether you are building a client or a server.

Consult the [documentation here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc9.7) to see which files are needed and for what.